# Figure out which app is using Java

Tags: macos, mac, java, cpu

If I check my activity monitor there is an instance of java that is constantly taking 5% CPU or more. I know that there is some app that are using java on my system and therefore my question is:

Is there any way to figure out what app that is using java without closing all running apps?

Note: All "main" applications is closed (No apps i dock) so I know that that it is one of my background/menubar applications.

Comment: Does the output of `ps aux | grep java` in Terminal give a hint?

Comment: Yeah, it tells me that -Dapp and -DappBaseName is related to CrashPlan but I quit that app and there is no traces left in activity monitor about it so I don't understand how it could be running.

Comment: The Java process is the trace then :-)

Comment: CrashPlan runs a background task as well that is controlled by a Launch Daemon in '/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist'. So to stop Crashplan running at all you need to delete this file or change it so it is not enabled.